# Help with a basic geometry question

Tags: geometry, area

Would anyone be able to explain a solution to the question in the image please?

[image: The Question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to solve a second degree equation:
[image]

Comment: Thanks I should have realised it was a trinomial :)

Answer (score 1):

The area of a triangle is one-half times the base times the height. So we have $$\frac12 (2x)(2x-5) = 7\;.$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: I get to that although I am not sure where to go from there?

Comment: @JeffH, solve for $x$. Multiply out the left-hand side and you will get a quadratic. Then move the seven over and solve for $x$ by factoring the quadratic.

Comment: Sorry I know I need to work out x but I haven't been able to

Comment: What have you got so far? Frankly, right now you are coming off as a student who doesn't want to do their own homework and just wants me to type up the answer for you. :/

Comment: This is not homework. I have tried to solve the equation, I know what the answer is (x=7/2). I am unsure on how to get the answer so I was asking for help

Comment: But **what** have you done to try to solve the equation? **What** exactly are you stuck on? See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) if you need help nicely typing up what you've done so far.

Comment: I tried to work out x although I got x=√8.5/4

Comment: **WHAT** did you do to get $x=\sqrt{8.5}/4$???